# Upload data, change data frame and download result using shiny package

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am new to R and maybe someone could help me with a question about shiny.

I want to upload a data.frame as csv with shiny, after that I want to change the data.frame by some calculations, then I want to download the data.frame again with the shiny application. Lets say I have a dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(value1=c(1:100), value2=c(101:200)) #data frame I uploaded
x$value2 <- x$value2/x$value1 # calculation
# then download it
```

with the help of the shiny gallery my code looks like this so far: (where I only tried to upload a csv and download it again with no calculations):

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                     'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                   '"'),
      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('contents')
    )
  )
)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
             quote=input$quote)
  })

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste(input$file1, '.csv', sep='') 
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(file1, file)
    }
  )
```

}

I can upload a csv this is no problem, but the download does not work, I have no reference to the uploaded file..

Does somebody now the answer or could help me here? Maybe its a silly error but I started with R five days ago and this is all new to me.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works for me:

#### UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                  accept=c('text/csv', 
                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                           '.csv')),
        tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                     c(Comma=',',
                       Semicolon=';',
                       Tab='\t'),
                     ','),
        radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                     c(None='',
                       'Double Quote'='"',
                       'Single Quote'="'"),
                     '"'),
        downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('contents')
      )
    )
  )
)
```

#### Server

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    getData <- reactive({

      inFile <- input$file1

      if (is.null(input$file1))
        return(NULL)

      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
               quote=input$quote)

    })


    output$contents <- renderTable(

      getData()

    )

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

      filename = function() { 
        paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },

      content = function(file) {

        write.csv(getData(), file)

      })

}
```

#### Run

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see I create a reactive object to generate the data and keep it saved. You do not save the data anywhere in your code when you use `read.csv`. You just read the data and feed it to `renderTable` but the data is not saved in R. Essentially you need to save the data and also make it available to other `ouput$...` functions. This is what `reactive` does on this occasion. Saves the file and makes it available to the other output functions.

There is a tutorial [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/)

Comment: Many thanks this solves everything! (and thanks for the link)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, try save() instead of paste

Comment: thanks, but this does not change anything, paste is also given in the example of the shiny gallery so I think this is not the problem?! https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-download.html