# Is there an R function for reading only (excluding upload) in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, large-data, large-files, shinyapps

I have a DAT file sized > 5 GB and containing >41 milions of row. To make it executable in certain software, I need to convert it to be CSV by some manipulation, of course, before print it. Because of size, it's imposible to make it done well in MS Excel. So I prefer to use RStudio at the end.

I have already tried by just coding in Rmd space, and succeeded. But my colleages has the same problem, so I initiated to deploy the code in Shiny in order to let them not install R and RStudio but just access a certain shiny app I should have created.

these are codes that totally worked. I just put them in Rmd.

```
data <- read.table("xxx.dat")
uniq <- unique(data[,3])
df <- data.frame(uniq)
library(stringr)
data$V9 <- str_replace_all(data$V8,"-","0") 
uniq <- as.character(uniq)

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  aa <- ifelse(nchar(uniq[i])==7,paste(substr(uniq[i],1,4),substr(uniq[i],6,7),sep=""),paste(substr(uniq[i],1,5),substr(uniq[i],7,8),sep=""))
  write.table(data.frame(filter(data,V3==df[i,1]))[,c(6,7,9)],sprintf('%s.csv',aa),row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=",")

}
```

what I expected was to create it in Shiny, so my friends could use it without installing R and RStudio. In shiny page, I just wanted to put 3 parts;

1. ActionButton to browse the file I want to convert (include filename)
2. ActionButton to browse the destination I would put the file I had converted (directory)
3. ActionButton to convert it

Anybody could help me please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload data, change data frame and download result using shiny package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856577/upload-data-change-data-frame-and-download-result-using-shiny-package)

Comment: Not same. The link you shared totally works for SMALL size file, but I play with file > 5 GB.

Comment: This has already been asked before as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191701/r-shiny-fileinput-large-files

Comment: Furthermore, please read [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html) - By default, Shiny limits file uploads to 5MB per file. You can modify this limit by using the `shiny.maxRequestSize` option. For example, adding `options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)` to the top of app.R would increase the limit to 30MB.

Comment: Thank you. I frankly already read it. By the way, is it possible that reading it only (without uploading) in Shiny?

Comment: That depends on your setup - somehow the users data needs to be accessible to the PC hosting your shiny app. This can be done via uploading the data, mapping a shared folder to the PC running R (and shiny) or using a database.